# What is Carlo Maria Viganò's religious order?

Tags: catholicism, history, priests, religious-orders

I was wondering in which religious order did Viganò got ordained as a priest (is he franciscan, jesuit, dominican)?

Comment: This is a question for google and not for this site. But I googled it for you.

Answer (score 3):

According to [catholic-hierarchy.org](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bvigano.html) Carlo Maria Viganò was ordained as priest of the diocese of Pavia on 24th of March 1968.

So he was a (normal) diocesan priest before becoming bishop and is no member of any order.

Answer (score 0):

**What is Carlo Maria Viganò's religious order?**

Archbishop Carlo Maria Viganò's was ordained a diocesan priest for the Diocese of Pavia, Italy on 24 March 1968. Being a diocesan priest and not a religious priest, he is not and never has been a member of any Religious Order to date.

- In 1973 he entered the diplomatic service of the Holy See and worked at the papal diplomatic missions in Iraq and Great Britain.
- From 1978 to 1989, he held posts at the Secretariat of State.
- On April 4 1989 he was named Special Envoy and Permanent Observer of the Holy See to the Council of Europe in Strasbourg.
- **On 3 April 1992, he was appointed Titular Archbishop of Ulpiana** and Apostolic Nuncio to Nigeria by Pope John Paul II. He was consecrated by the Pope, with Cardinals Franciszek Macharski and Angelo Sodano serving as co-consecrators, on 26 April.
- At the close of his mission to Nigeria, he was assigned to functions within the Secretariat of State as delegate for Pontifical Representations, making him the personnel chief for the Roman curia in addition to Vatican diplomats. He served in this role until he became Secretary General of the Governatorate on 16 July 2009.
- In 2009, Viganò was appointed Secretary General of the Vatican City Governatorate.
- On 13 August 2011, Secretary of State Tarcisio Bertone informed Viganò that Pope Benedict was appointing him Nuncio to the United States.
- In January 2016, Archbishop Vigano submitted his resignation as required when he turned 75 years old. On 12 April 2016, Pope Francis accepted Viganò's resignation and named Archbishop Christophe Pierre to succeed him as nuncio to the United States.

[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Maria_Vigan%C3%B2)

**At present, Archbishop Carlo Maria Viganò is living in an undisclosed location, as a self-imposed exile.**

[He called on the pope to resign. Now this archbishop is in an undisclosed location.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/this-archbishop-called-on-the-pope-to-resign-now-hes-in-an-undisclosed-location/2019/06/09/bb69c346-71b5-11e9-9331-30bc5836f48e_story.html?noredirect=on)